# A device he have a great interest in

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

A group of friends challenged Mark, the brightest among them, to an escape room challenge (two rooms). They know Mark have a wide range of knowledge. But for this one they thought even the bright Mark would have a hard time figuring out the answer.

The instructions were following:

"You have 30 minutes to solve part one of the puzzle in the first room - if you can't, too bad. If you manage to solve it however then ring the bell and we'll unlock the door to the right of you. Enter the door, sit down at the table and solve part two of the puzzle. This time you'll have 1 hour to solve it. If you figure out the answer, just shout it out loud and we'll give you your reward. You have to answer correct on your first try though. Good luck!"

It didn't take long before Mark solved part one, well before the 30 minutes. So he rang the bell. They unlocked the door and Mark entered the room, saw the table and briefly saw some large rectangular plate on it. But just within milliseconds after the door got closed behind him, the part one of the puzzle suddenly made sense.

Being Mark, he managed to figure it out of course and shouted the answer with great joy ("they really know me, these guys" he thought to himself) and got his reward. But it wasn't too easy.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

**Can you tell me what Mark shouted?**

Comment: Hmm so, if Mark is the brightest of them, then the non-brighter ones are not going to make such a hard puzzle out of this ;) .

Comment: They're pretty bright too ;)

Comment: Is the grammar of the title intentional? :0

Comment: Are you sure the bottom right square is correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's correct. But I gotta say, I made this puzzle overcomplicated. And I've been thinking back and forth whether or not I should use similar logic to another more straightforward puzzle. That is, to close this puzzle and post another one (with similar logic) I'm more satisfied with.

Comment: Any way you can drop a hint for step one instead of canning it? I worked out the second part ages ago but can't apply it without first solving the first part! :)

Comment: Tbh, I feel the logic in this puzzle is overcomplicated and is not satisfactory overall. So I rather use similar methodology in another puzzle but with a "better logic". I don't know how I was fully satisfied with it in the first place :D That's great you solved the second part though, which in my eyes was the hardest part. So, my apologies, but I rather see this one get closed

Comment: Ultimately your choice :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a transcription of the puzzle from the first room:

Top left tile:

```
L I C T R P  
B Q N E T U  
M T S D O P  
A F Y B K A  
W G I E X N  
H O F X S O
```

Top right tile:

```
Z W I U R I  
R O K N F T  
P C E U N V  
S J Q U L N  
D G R E T O  
S F B K U S
```

Bottom left tile:

```
K G D P E V  
U T R L I E  
Y M N I L E  
U S R K Y U  
Q Y B P R F  
L E U W I O
```

Bottom right tile:

```
I A K O S L  
W P E U I T  
S I U O T I  
G U G Y J F  
O P L U S H  
T A M W R K
```

Center tile:

```
1 3 4 4 2 1  
3 4 1 3 1 4  
3 2 2 3 2 4  
4 1 3 1 3 1  
2 4 2 2 4 1  
2 2 3 4 0 3
```

Possible spoiler:

> I suspect the symbols above the piles noting some kind of traversal order and the center tile being a mask that has to be applied on each of them somehow.